# Dockerize Web App

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, web-applications

I'm a student and currently in an internship. While talking to a colleague about the project I need to do next year he mentioned I should dockerize my web app.

I was wondering if someone could clear up some questions I had about this.

1. If I dockerize a web app, does this mean I only need to have my AWS server up for my CI tests, and therefore never needing to worry about credit running out?
2. Can my web app be pulled down onto any machine (assuming I have added it to docker hub & the machine has docker installed)?

I am extremely new to docker and have little/no knowledge in the subject.

What intrigues me is that I was told this would be impressive to whoever is grading my project next year.

Comment: 1. Depends on how your webapp is served. If your client is supposed to deploy it locally using Docker then I'm not sure how you could exhaust your AWS credits with it?
2. Yes, that's the beauty of _dockerizing_ an app, it means people will be able to run it on their system without the need to install dependencies and regardless of their OS/environment.

Comment: I don't understand #1, if you're hosting your app somewhere, it'll cost you some money. dockerized or not. #2 is yes, you can run it anywhere with docker runtime. Adding docker to your skills will definitely make you attractive to the current job market.

Comment: The one caveat on point 2 is that you must be an administrator to run Docker images, but you can generally develop and deploy basic Web applications as a general unprivileged user.

Comment: My advice if you are very new to this space is to learn general Web development first, and don't try to throw Docker into the mix very early.  The Linux/shell-scripting/networking knowledge you need to effectively use Docker is different from the JavaScript/CSS/HTML knowledge you need for Web development.  Something that's well-built and works well will always be more effective than something that tries to use the latest technologies for their own sake.

Comment: Me personally, I'd go with Gitlab. 1. You can have CI in gitlab, also supporting docker and you can run tests right there. 2. Gitlab has a docker registry, so you can have your image there and can pull from there onto any machine, which has docker.

Comment: Thank you all for your input. This has helped and I can go research some of the things suggested